# How to make Java 6, which fails SSL connection with "SSL peer shut down incorrectly", succeed like Java 7?

Tags: java, ssl, handshake, sslhandshakeexception

I'm seeing an SSL connection from a client running Java 6 fail with an exception like:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:133)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:462)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863)
    ... 41 more
```

The server is a Tomcat 7-based app, running on Java 7, Linux, and on Amazon EC2, for what that's worth.

I've found a lot of suggestions on possible casues, including connecting accidentally to a non-SSL port, etc. I believe I've ruled it all out, mostly because the *exact same client works when running Java 7 with no change*. (OS X in both cases.)

Below I include the debug output from Java 6's and Java 7's SSL connection procedure. My question to experts is, **does this suggest that some possible cipher or protocol setting, maybe a default in Java 7, could be enabled in Java 6 to make it work**?

Java 6:

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1363993281 bytes = { 77, 153, 100, 72, 45, 178, 253, 243, 195, 167, 17, 151, 39, 247, 148, 102, 213, 129, 39, 17, 26, 139, 157, 154, 63, 88, 41, 160 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 81
main, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 110
main, received EOFException: error
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
```

Java 7:

```
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(0) called
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1363993435 bytes = { 131, 83, 80, 186, 215, 90, 171, 131, 231, 18, 184, 183, 249, 155, 197, 204, 73, 1, 74, 79, 32, 142, 236, 28, 111, 37, 58, 255 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com]
```

Comment: Is the failure visible from the client?  I've seen these types of errors before as part of normal SSL negotiation, i.e. it "worked" from the user's point of view.

Comment: With Java 6, the client hello falls back to SSLv2 whereas with Java 7 it seems to be conducted with TLSv1. I believe that JSSE under Java 6 does not officially support SSL V2 but I need to research that

Comment: Using ` openssl s_client -connect servername:443` you can debug what protocol the server supports and perform tests by forcing flags like `ssl2`, `ssl2`, check [this](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html)

Comment: @Taylor yes the request fails every time in Java 6, and the connection does not succeed.

Comment: @BGR yes I've confirmed that it only supports `tls1` and `ssl3`, as expected I guess. Now I'm looking at how to make Java 6 not use SSLv2.

Comment: @SeanOwen - how do we debug this issue and find out the cause ? i.e. arrive at the same solution as you ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Bruno's answer was the correct one in the end. This is most easily controlled by the `https.protocols` system property. This is how you are able to control what the factory method returns. Set to "TLSv1" for example.

Comment: It leads to problems when you want to use two protocols instead of one. For example, `SSLv3` and `TLSv1`. This `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,SSLv3` will lead to exceptions if you try to connect either SSLv3 or TLSv1.

Comment: @Dragon Really? What exceptions? Why?

Answer (score 6):

It seems that in the debug log for `Java 6` the request is send in `SSLv2` format.

> main, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 110

This is not mentioned as enabled by default in Java 7.
Change the client to use SSLv3 and above to avoid such interoperability issues.

Look for differences in `JSSE` providers in [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider) and [Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunJSSEProvider)

Comment: Yep that's good evidence and indeed the SSLv2 appears to be the problem. This sort of leads to my answer here, although @EJP is right that it would be best to find a way to turn off SSLv2 explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

Remove "SSLv2ClientHello" from the enabled protocols on the client SSLSocket or HttpsURLConnection.

Comment: I think that's exactly right, though I am not sure how to do it. I'm building an `SSLSocketFactory` for the platform. `SSLContext.createSSLEngine()` makes an `SSLEngine` which has methods to set (not remove, it seems) protocols. But I don't think this helps the `SSLSocketFactory`. The `SSLContext` also only lets you ask for a protocol and not disable whatever others that entails (?). If you happen to know how this goes let me know.

Comment: Get the enabled protocols, remove "SSLv2ClientHello", and set them to what remains.

Comment: I don't believe there's any such method though. At least I can't see it on `SSLContext` or `SSLSocketFactory`. `SSLEngine` is not helpful I believe since the framework will be making its own later. Will keep looking.

Comment: Any such method as what? What are you talking about? getEnabledCipherSuites() and setEnabledCipherSuites() both exist. You can also set a system property to control this for the default SSLContext.

Comment: Yes @EJP but that is on `SSLSocket` and I'm making a factory... which probably means wrapping with a custom `SSLSocketFactory`. Seems like there should be something cleaner. I'll look for this sys property.

Comment: @SeanOwen, if you're using `HttpsURLConnection`, the [`https.protocols` system property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization) should help you set the enabled cipher suites.

Comment: Confirmed that `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1` makes this work in Java 6.

Comment: @SeanOwen If you're creating a socket factory, you get the socket, or create it yourself, and you can call these methods, before you return it.

Answer (score 3):

update the server arguments from  -Dhttps.protocols=SSLv3 to -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,SSLv3

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sslFactory.createSocket(host, port);
socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"SSLv3", "TLSv1"});
```