# Jsoup error Remote host closed connection during handshake

Tags: jsoup

Thanks for your time to read my question - I am using Eclipse IDE.
I want Jsoup to connect a https url - https://www.icegate.gov.in/  using `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.icegate.gov.in/").get();`

but it giving error  `Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake` while when i use same code for other https like linkedin then it works ... I don't know how to resolve this issue.

I got certificate of that website and installed in my jre/lib/security folder but it also not helped me.

How to add these certificate & jks in eclipse.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxxxx").get();

    Element summaryDetails = doc.getElementById("profile");


    System.out.println("Summary Details  is - "+ summaryDetails.text());

    Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect("https://www.icegate.gov.in/").get();
}
```

And error I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:512)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
    at com.deepak.TestLinkedIn.main(TestLinkedIn.java:39)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:482)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run java with these VM arguments:

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
```

more info in these other questions:

[SSL handshake alert: unrecognized_name error since upgrade to Java 1.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615645/ssl-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name-error-since-upgrade-to-java-1-7-0)

[How to make Java 6, which fails SSL connection with "SSL peer shut down incorrectly", succeed like Java 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589880/how-to-make-java-6-which-fails-ssl-connection-with-ssl-peer-shut-down-incorrec)

Bytheway, I didn't need to add any certificate to my truststore because site certificate's CA was already trusted.

Comment: My console app was working monthes, but today I getting same error. Do not know why, but surprisingly it works